# DIV not resizing with window due to flexbox align-items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="images">
    <img class="image" src="Test/0001.png" alt="Option">
    <img class="image" src="Test/0002.png" alt="Option">
    <img class="image" src="Test/0012.png" alt="Option">
    <img class="image" src="Test/0014.png" alt="Option">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following JS function I use to resize a canvas using Fabric JS functions:

```
window.onresize = () => {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

    const ratio          = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
    const wrapperWidth = wrapper.clientWidth;
    const scale          = wrapperWidth / canvas.getWidth();
    const zoom           = canvas.getZoom() * scale;

    canvas.setDimensions({width: wrapperWidth, height: wrapperWidth / ratio});
    canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);
}
```

This HTML + JavaScript works and resizes my canvas properly, but the issue comes when I want to add this CSS so the `content` and `images` divs are centered on the screen:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  gap: 5vh;
}
```

I've seen the issue is with the line `align-items: center`, when I delete it, the canvas resizes accordingly to the JavaScript listener I declared but when it's present, it breaks the functionality and the canvas doesn't resize anymore because the `wrapper` div doesn't change it's width with the window resize anymore.

Why's that? How can I align the items to the center without breaking the canvas resizing function?

**Edit**

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Fabric.js Image Editor</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="images">
      <img class="image" src="Test/0001.png" alt="Option">
      <img class="image" src="Test/0002.png" alt="Option">
      <img class="image" src="Test/0012.png" alt="Option">
      <img class="image" src="Test/0014.png" alt="Option">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  gap: 5vh;
}

.images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: 1000px;
}

.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.image:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

index.js:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

fabric.Image.fromURL("Test/IMG_0008.jpg", function(img) {
  var scaleFactor = Math.min(window.innerWidth / img.width, window.innerHeight / img.height);
  scaleFactor *= 0.8;

  canvas.setWidth(img.width * scaleFactor);
  canvas.setHeight(img.height * scaleFactor);

  img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
  img.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
});

document.querySelectorAll(".image").forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(element.src, function(img) {
      if (img.width > canvas.width || img.height > canvas.height) {
        img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width / 2);
        img.scaleToHeight(canvas.height / 2);
      }

      img.setControlsVisibility({ mt: false, mb: false, ml: false, mr: false });

      canvas.add(img);
      canvas.centerObject(img);
      canvas.setActiveObject(img);
    });
  });
});

const resizeCanvas = () => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

    const ratio          = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
    const wrapperWidth = wrapper.clientWidth;
    const scale          = wrapperWidth / canvas.getWidth();
    const zoom           = canvas.getZoom() * scale;

    canvas.setDimensions({width: wrapperWidth, height: wrapperWidth / ratio});
    canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
window.onload = resizeCanvas;
```

Comment: The container wraps all the html you provided? Where is the rest of css? Canvas is height 0 in default. You are not giving all information.

Comment: Yes, some additional code is needed, ie the containment of everything. You description of your needs and the error still needs more clarity. I can't tell if you desire a standard thumbnail strip at the bottom of the screen or if you want it floating dead-center for some reason. Secondly, I have a feeling that your resize code probably needs a second look when in extremes of viewport aspect ratio. Hard to address any of this without seeing your overall layout (with or without `canvas`).

Comment: One clear update to make: The resize logic should live in it's own function e.g. `setCanvasDimensions()`, and you'd call this twice: 1. on page load, 2. on window resize.

Comment: @digitalniweb @Kalnode Thanks for your answers. I edited the answer with the full HTML, CSS and JS content I'm using. I originally made a mistake where the `container` only contained the canvas, but it also contains the `images` I edited that as well. Hope this is now clear enough to see the issue with `align-items: center` not resizing the canvas properly. I'll try to make a video of the issue if it's still not clear

Comment: I have a feeling you just want to add width: 100%; to .wrapper because of the flex you added. If the code worked before the flex.

Comment: `.wrapper { align-self: stretch; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and successfully reproduced your example, then the issue you're experiencing is when you shrink the page and try to zoom it back in. When zooming back in, you cannot achieve the original size.

If you observe in your code, the width of the wrapper always remains fixed to the size of the image. This is problematic because when I shrink the page, you scale down the image, and the wrapper size adjusts to this small size. If I enlarge the page, the small image remains small, and so does the wrapper.

#### Solution

When you load the main image into the `canvas`, the `canvas` captures the current page size and sets a specific size based on the image. You can save this as the fixed width of the `wrapper`. In addition, you'll need to set the `max-width` of the `wrapper` to `100vw` in CSS to prevent overflow, and the browser will automatically shrink the `wrapper` width, which your resize function would have already tracked.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100vw; /* HERE - Maximum 100vw (maximum screen width), so the photo won't overflow */
}
```

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL("https://picsum.photos/1000/1000", function(img) {
  // ...
  
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

  wrapper.style.width = `${canvas.width}px`; // HERE - Setting a fixed width based on the original size (img.width * scaleFactor)
});
```

I suggested just one example for fixing the wrapper's width. You can fix the original size however you want. In my example, I simply wrote in the CSS, `width: 500px;` which I later made a bit more flexible in JavaScript (what you can see this in the line `wrapper.style.width`).

As @digitalniweb also suggested, using `width: 100%` could be a solution, although I didn't choose this because I don't like distorting images (and in this case, there would be a realistic chance of that happening... **instead, I aligned with the canvas dimensions... (`img.width * scaleFactor`).

#### Example

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://picsum.photos/500/500", function(img) {
  var scaleFactor = Math.min(window.innerWidth / img.width, window.innerHeight / img.height);
  scaleFactor *= 0.8;

  canvas.setWidth(img.width * scaleFactor);
  canvas.setHeight(img.height * scaleFactor);

  img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
  img.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  wrapper.style.width = `${canvas.width}px`; // HERE - img.width * scaleFactor
});

document.querySelectorAll(".image").forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(element.src, function(img) {
      if (img.width > canvas.width || img.height > canvas.height) {
        img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width / 2);
        img.scaleToHeight(canvas.height / 2);
      }

      img.setControlsVisibility({ mt: false, mb: false, ml: false, mr: false });

      canvas.add(img);
      canvas.centerObject(img);
      canvas.setActiveObject(img);
    });
  });
});

const resizeCanvas = () => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

  const wrapperWidth = wrapper.clientWidth;
  const canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
  const canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
  const canvasZoom  = canvas.getZoom();
  
  const ratio = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
  const scale = wrapperWidth / canvasWidth;
  const zoom =  canvasZoom * scale;
  
  const newCanvasHeight = wrapperWidth / ratio;

  canvas.setDimensions({ width: wrapperWidth, height: newCanvasHeight });
  canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  resizeCanvas();
});

window.onload = () => {
  resizeCanvas();
};
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  gap: 5vh;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100vw; /* HERE */
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.image:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="images">
    <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/888/888" alt="Option">
    <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/555/555" alt="Option">
    <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/222/222" alt="Option">
    <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/111/111" alt="Option">
  </div>
</div>
```